# SQL query: Incorrect Syntax error

Tags: c#, sql, syntax

I'm getting an error

> incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE

with the following SQL statement:

```
SqlCommand scInsertCostSpilt = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [ASSETS_CC] ([DEPT], [CC], [PER_CENT]) WHERE [ASSET_NO] = @AssetNumber)" +
"Values (@AssetNumber, @Dept, @CC, @PerCent)" , DataAccess.AssetConnection);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Watch out when you are combining strings into a command: you might need a space just before the "Values".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have written wrong query.
Update as below given query:

```
INSERT INTO [ASSETS_CC] ([DEPT], [CC], [PER_CENT]) Values ( @Dept, @CC, @PerCent)
```

Comment: Have you tested it? I think it shouldn't work: There should be no WHERE in an INSERT statement ...

Comment: @DynamicVariable It is strange that it should work, because the number of items on the name list is different from the number of items on the value list.

Answer (score 7):

In SQL insert statements do not have a `WHERE` clause (which makes sense, because the record is not there yet). You put the IDs together with all other values if you would like to insert a new record, or use an `UPDATE` statement if you would like to change an existing record.

```
INSERT INTO [ASSETS_CC] ([ASSET_NO], [DEPT], [CC], [PER_CENT]) 
VALUES (@AssetNumber, @Dept, @CC, @PerCent)
```

or

```
UPDATE [ASSETS_CC]
SET [DEPT] =  @Dept, [CC] = @CC, [PER_CENT] = @PerCent
WHERE [ASSET_NO] = @AssetNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go.

```
SqlCommand scInsertCostSpilt = new SqlCommand("INSERT ASSETS_CC (DEPT, CC, PER_CENT) Values (@AssetNumber, @Dept, @CC, @PerCent)" , DataAccess.AssetConnection);
```

Comment: @AVD - the INTO keyword is optional (in SqlServer)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `where` clause which you can't use in `Insert` statement.

```
SqlCommand scInsertCostSpilt = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ASSETS_CC (DEPT, CC, PER_CENT) Values (@AssetNumber, @Dept, @CC, @PerCent)" , DataAccess.AssetConnection);
```